# How to include an "if" and "for" loop in a function in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, function

I'm trying to write a function looking like this.

```
def function(statement):

if statement:
    for loop
else: 
    continue
...

function(statement = True)
```

function(statement = True) should then run the for loop. If statement is for example false, it continues with the rest of the function. It's current not working, so any help on how to implement this is appreciated.

Comment: It looks like you have the right idea. Just get your indentation (scoping) correct. The if/else should be one indentation in from the def, and the for loop one more indentation in from the if.

Comment: continue is only valid in a loop so just drop the else: part.  Loop syntax is `for x in y` where x is what you get out of the loop at y is something iterable like a list.

Comment: What isn't working for you? The indentation isn't currently correct and you can't run `continue` outside of a loop.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I suggested above (you need to spell out the loop):

```
def function(statement):
  if statement:
    for x in y:
       ...
```